# Angular2 ngClass with the same class but different conditions

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

How to use `[ngClass]` with the same `.className` but with two different conditions?

I tried separating them like so - but it doesn't append the class for some reason.

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-success': condition1, 'btn-success': condition2 }">My Button</button>
```

Maybe something like this, its the same as above its not appending the `btn-success` class to the button.

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-success': condition1 && condition2 }">My Button</button>
```

Can't find anywhere if this has been done, I know you can use two different classes with one condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OR` operator, not `AND`, because you want to apply class if one of these conditions is true:

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-success': condition1 || condition2 }">My Button</button>
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the quick response, didn't think of `OR` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just use a function or a getter (this is actually the preferred practice, minimizing conditionals in markup, it's a common reason to have a CL kicked back, all kinds of reasons besides the obvious anti-spaghetti, such as how the build process deals with templates, minification/uglification, etc).

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="computeButtonClass ( )">My Button</button>

<button class="btn" [ngClass]="buttonClass">My Button</button>
```

Controller:

```
computeButtonClass ( ) {
   etc. etc.
}

get buttonClass ( ) {
 etc. etc. 
}
```

I kind of went the other way for a while, along the lines of "it's easy this way and if the framework enables it why not use it," but like the elvis operator, you find that the more you put in the markup, the more unwieldy it gets. Keep your logic out of your markup unless there's a really specific reason not to. Separation of concerns, etc. etc.